# Changing SSL Cert results in "Connection Interupted Error"

Tags: iis-6, ssl-certificate, wildcard

We are trying to apply a new certificate to our IIS webserver.  However, whenever I go to IIS's admin interface and select the new cert,  any browser requests come back with a "Connection Interrupted" Error,  If I put the old cert back, it works.
The Old cert is a GoDaddy SSL "named" cert, ie web.domain.com   while the new one is a wildcard cert, also from GoDaddy.  The server is Windows 2003, with IIS 6.0.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you aren't using host headers for the site you are trying to apply the certificate to.